# CSS height problem: How can i make height response to other child div and make sure it not overflow

Tags: html, css

So I have this div:

```
  <div style="height: 500px;">
    <div id="box-1" style="height: ??px;"> Header</div>
    <div id="NeedToResponeHeight"> Container ,table or chart</div>
  </div>
```

How to make this NeedToResponeHeight max-height + box-1 height = 500px,
I dont want parent div to overflow , but NeedToResponeHeight div is Ok to overflow

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you're wondering why you get downvotes on this: Its a very poorly written up question. If you put in more effort describing the problem next time, this won't happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to achieve your desired layout:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column
}

#box-1 {
  height: 40px;
  background: wheat;
}

#NeedToResponeHeight {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px;" class="wrap">
  <div id="box-1"> Header</div>
  <div id="NeedToResponeHeight"> Container ,table or chart</div>
</div>
```